# Can I return an async value (a Promise) from a Meteor helper?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

A Promise is an object type which serves as a placeholder for a future result,
such as the body of an HTTP request, or the return value of a Meteor method call.
Basically any function that forces you to pass a callback to recieve its
return value (instead of just returning it) is said to be an async function,
and the value it gives back can be represented by a Promise.

The issue in Meteor is that `helper` methods are only intended to work with
synchronous values - such as the text in a web page, or the contents of a 
Minimongo collection. When you return a Promise from one, the helper

- shows `[object Promise]` instead of the resolved value
- does not update when the promise resolves

Some attempts at solving this exist: [simple:reactive-method](https://atmospherejs.com/simple/reactive-method)
and [arsnebula:reactive-promise](https://atmospherejs.com/arsnebula/reactive-promise), but they require you to change your helpers to a certain style, or only work with `Meteor.call` instead of just simply allowing a generic promise to be returned.

Is there something existing I've overlooked, or is there a solution in the works? I've been experimenting with this for some time, and may work on something myself if there's not an official answer.

Comment: Please give example code of what you've tried so far.

Comment: Good question. You're basically looking to use `simple:reactive-method` with a promise instead of a method, but otherwise it's the same idea.

Comment: Yes, @AndrewMao, but ReactiveMethod is not chainable, not a full promise..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even with respect to other libraries out there, I think the answer for now is to go with the package `deanius:promise` (disclaimer: I authored it, with input from the authors of some other packages).

It does what the question asks, and adds some nice touches like controllable error and loading messages.